# Using gluLookAt to move camera in 2D iPhone game?

Tags: opengl, iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to use gluLookAt to move the camera in my iPhone game, but every time I've tried to use gluLookAt my screen just goes "blank" ( grey in this case )

I'm trying to render a simple triangle and to move the camera, this is my code:

to setup my scene I do:

```
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(-90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //using iPhone in horizontal mode
glOrthof(-240, 240, -160, 160, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

then my "triangle rendering" code looks like:

```
GLfloat  triangle[] = {0, 100, 100, 0, -100, 0,};
glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &triangle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

This draws a red triangle in the middle of the screen, when I try to apply gluLookAt ( I got the implementation of the function from Cocos2D so I asume it's correct ), i do:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1); // try to move the camera a bit ?

GLfloat  triangle[] = {0, 100, 100, 0, -100, 0,};
glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &triangle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

This leads me to grey screen (glClearColor is grey), I've tried all sort of things and read what I've found about gluLookAt on the net, but no luck :(, if someone could explain me or show me how to move to move the camera in a top-down fashion ( zelda, etc ), I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's generally** no reason to use gluLookAt in a 2D game, it is meant for setting the camera position in 3D space. Use the simpler and faster glTranslatef instead.

If you really want your specific example to work then something like:

```
gluLookAt(200,0,1,200,0,0,1,0,0);
```

would move everything up by 200 pixels. But you could get the same effect by replacing gluLookAt with glTranslatef:

```
glTranslatef(-200, 0, 0);
```

** cocos2d supports this method of setting the camera for special '3D' effects. If that's what you want then you need to better understand how gluLookAt works. The [projection example](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html) by Nate Robin can be a good place to start visualizing how projection works with that command. With that said, you should still be able to get similar 3D effects with just translation/scaling/rotation.

Edit: About gluLookAt

[gluLookAt](http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/gluLookAt.html) describes the position and orientation of the eye/camera in space. The first 3 arguments specify where the eye is located, the next 3 arguments specify where the eye is looking, and the last 3 specify the up direction that tells us how the camera is tilted. What this really does is define a viewing transformation by building a matrix.

In the gluLookAt example I gave, the eye position is (200, 0, 1). Because you rotated the projection matrix around the z axis earlier, I have to change x to move vertically and y to move horizontally. For the z coordinate, the point that we're looking at (200, 0, 0) should be in front of the eye, meaning you can't use a z coordinate  of -1 for example because the look at point would be behind the eye. In this example it doesn't matter what z value you use as long as it is positive (comes before the look at point which has a z of 0).

The camera normally always looks straight ahead in 2D games so we use the same x and y for the look at point (200, 0) but we move it away from the camera in z direction (0). Finally we need to define a vector that specifies the up direction, this is normally (0, 1, 0) because the x-z plane represents the ground in many games. Since you rotated the projection matrix around the z axis I guess you could also use (1, 0, 0) and then you wouldn't need to swap x and y coordinates when specifying the position of the eye and look at point.

I still think it's simpler to just use the glTranslate and glRotate functions. If you familiarize yourself with their use you can easily write a simple camera class without the overhead of calling gluLookAt.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!, I was wondering if you could explain your gluLookAt example arguments a bit ? Why the 1 in the eyeZ parameter ( third arg ) , and why the 1 in the upY ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does that help?